# Can Pythons HTMLParser edit/change a HTML elements innerText or ONLY read it

Tags: python, html, html-parsing

I am using the python module HTMLParser.py

*I am able to parse HTML correctly but is there an option to change a HTML elements data(innerText)?*

**Do you know how I can do this with the module HTMLParser?**

Comment: highly recommend [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) if you can

Answer (score 0):

No, the HTMLParser does just that: it parses through your HTML.

You're probably looking for [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/). It'll create a ParseTree--a Pythonic tree of objects representing the HTML elements of your document. Then, you can search up the object (element) you want, assign it a new value, and voila!

Stolen shamelessly from the [documentation](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html#Replacing%20one%20Element%20with%20Another):

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup("<b>Argh!</b>")
soup.find(text="Argh!").replaceWith("Hooray!")
print soup
# <b>Hooray!</b>
```